# Advantages of sending printing tasks to printers directly

Tags: java, printing

I have written a java application, it works perfectly, however, it requires printer drivers to be installed. From technical side, how much faster will it be sending tasks directly to a printer ( on slow pc's for example), is there any significant difference in speed or maybe some other disadvantages? Here i'm trying to understand if it is worth investing time into this task or keep the strategy with drivers. And i guess this will eliminate cases where there are  no drivers available for certain printers on windows 10 for example (just in theory), wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you plan to 'send tasks directly to the printer' ? The whole point of the printer driver is that it takes drawing operations from the operating system API and converts that into 'something else' whcih the printer understands.

In general there are about 6 possibilities:

1. PCL - An HP Page Description Language but many printers can process it natively.
2. PostScript - an Adobe Page Description Language, fewer printers support it, but its still common
3. PDF - another different Adobe PageDescription Language with some similarity to PostScript, again fewer printer support it because of ites resource requirements.
4. XPS - a Microsoft Page Description Language, not widely adopted for a number of reasons.
5. Basic bitmap - the host operating system renders to a bitmap at the resolution of the device and sends it. Used to be relatively common on low-end printers because its cheap to implement
6. something else. Some manufacturers, eg Epson, have their own languages.

On a Mac, PDF is the native format, and on a Windows 8 or better PC XPS is the native format. If your printer supports those then you can send a 'task' directly to it, possibly. If your java application isn't **creating** the content which needs to be printed but is merely a print server or processor, then you could send the data directly to the printer, because you will be receiving it in the printer native format (eg PostScript).

But in general, you need to convert your 'task' into some other page description language that the printer can understand, and send that to the printer.

Thus its not usually possible to print to a printer if you don't have a printer driver for it, because your operating system doesn't know how to create something the printer understands.

Comment: Thank you, now i have a much better understanding of things and know where exactly to continue my search for certain things!